# How to construct proof for $\forall x,n.x\leq n \wedge n\geq 0 \wedge x \geq 0 \wedge n< L \wedge x< L \implies F_2(x,n)\geq0$

Tags: first-order-logic

I have following axioms

$F_1$ and $F_2$ are function representing integer values of a 2-dimensinal matrix$(L\times L)$.

$b$ is natural number function

$n,x,L \in N$(represent natural numbers )

$b(0)=0$

$\forall n.n\geq 0 \wedge n< L\wedge F_1(n,n)<0 \implies b(n+1)=b(n)$

$\forall n.n\geq 0 \wedge n< L \wedge F_1(n,n)\geq0 \implies b(n+1)=b(n)+1$

$\forall n.n\geq 0 \wedge n< L \wedge F_1(n,n)\geq0 \implies F_2(b(n),n)=F_1(n,n)$

Need to prove the following

$\forall x,n.x\leq n \wedge n\geq 0 \wedge x \geq 0 \wedge n< L \wedge x< L  \implies F_2(x,n)\geq0$

Can anyone suggest how to construct the proof for above?

Comment: Entirely unclear what you mean. What is $fa(n,n)$? Use `\geq` instead of `>=`.  If $b$ is a function of one variable, what does $fb(b(n),n+1)$ mean?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need some more axioms!!

Comment: ThomasAndrews and Bram28. I have modified the question please a look

Comment: Can you explicitly write out the domain and codomain of all the functions in the problem? I'm very confused with your $fa,fb,a,b,fa$&$fb$ notation.

Comment: Use suffixes - `F_1, F_2` for $F_1, F_2$.  Right now, it just reads wrong. Also, the ampersand should probably be replaced by `\land`, which is rendered as the usual logical and symbol, $\land$. The spacing of the ampersand is hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I have updated accordingly. In future, I will take care of these things.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you can't prove it.  If you can show that $F_1(n,n) \ge 0$ then you can show (if you have induction) that $F_2(n,n)\ge 0$, but that still doesnot give you $F_2(x,n)$, and  there is nothing that forces $F_1(n,n) \ge 0$. Indeed, if $F_1(n,n)<0$, then you can't show that $F_2(x,n)\ge 0$ either.

Comment: thanks understand. Can you please help me understand how I can construct induction proof to show $F2(x,n)\geq0$ when $F1(n,n)\geq0$ is true

Comment: @Tom You would need an inductive axiom scheme, or at least the following instance of it: $(b(0)=0\land \forall n (b(n) = n \to b(n+1) =n+1)) \to \forall n b(n) =n$. So with that, and the assumption that $F_1(n,n) \ge 0$, you can prove $\forall n b(n) = n$. Hence, $F_2(x,n) = F_2(b(x),n)$ .... Oh, and then you get stuck!  Sorry!  OK, so ... You can't even prove $F_2(x,n) \ge 0$ when $F_1(n,n)\ge 0$! I'll update my answer ....